# Is Twitter Boostrap 3.x compatible with Jquery 2.x?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-2.0

I started using jquery 2.1.1 on a site that uses Bootstrap 3.x, and now bootstrap carousels won't work. Chrome web dev console says "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined "

Any help would be great!

Comment: You're probably not loading jQuery correctly.

Comment: make sure jQuery is loaded before being called.

Comment: Are you calling jQuery from a CDN or from local? If CDN sometimes it's slow.

Comment: I am calling it locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to Define JQuery.

Here is some code.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I was including Jquery locally